# react-native-code-push How to judge the update?

Tags: react-native, visual-studio-app-center, code-push, react-native-code-push

in app.js :

```
  componentDidMount() {
    codePush.sync({
      installMode: codePush.InstallMode.IMMEDIATE,
      updateDialog: true,
    });
  }
```

run app, show:

[image]

but my `versionName` Same as server!

Get the server return information through `flddler`:

```js
// GET https://codepush.appcenter.ms/v0.1/public/codepush/update_check/******

{
    "update_info": {
        "download_url": "https://codepushupdates.azureedge.net/storagev2/****",
        "is_available": true,
        "is_disabled": false,
        "target_binary_range": "****",
        "package_hash": "****",
        "label": "v6",
        "package_size": 107***,
        "update_app_version": false,
        "should_run_binary_version": false,
        "is_mandatory": false
    }
}
```

1.`update_app_version= false`

2.`versionName` Same as server `target_binary_range`

Why is there an update prompt?